# Create a sub-list of images

Tags: image, gallery

I have a slideshow at the top of my product description.

This slideshow uses photos from the images list of the product. I still have a photo gallery. To do the differentiation, the previous programmer uses the following rule : if a photo is excluded from gallery, then it is in slideshow.

This solution was good till now, as now, I want as well to have a photo for my category listing (i.e. small photo) and that photo should be neither in the slideshow nor in the gallery.

For the images, Is there a way to add a column (in backend), similar to the "Exclude" one, so that I can have a column "Slideshow" and restore the Exclude functionality to its original.

While I'm at it, how should I do then to fetch this so defined Slideshow list?

Comment: Did you manage to get the issue resolved?

Comment: as I answered below, no, but I have a potential idea where I need help, at least to get some pointers. basically, the idea would be to override the function that gets the image for the gallery (i.e. `$this->getGalleryImages()`), with an improved function `$this->getGalleryImages(0,100)`, the 2 numeric parameters being the position from and to I extract.

Comment: that could then give for my Gallery : `$this->getGalleryImages(0,100)` and for my slideshow `$this->getGalleryImages(101,200)`. I then re-abilitate my exclude function and can now create sub-lists of image, just putting the right code in the template and the right position in backend

Comment: I just need to find where is that damn function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got 2 working solutions

**1. From the template**

Display the image if the condition on the position is filled-in

```
  <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $i => $_image): ?>
        <?php if($_image->getPosition()<100){ //Display in Gallery only those with position below 100 ?>
        //Display the image here
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**2. overwrite the extracting function**

```
public function getGalleryImages($min=0,$max=0)
{
    if ($this->_isGalleryDisabled) {
        return array();
    }

    $product = $this->getProduct();
    if(!$product->hasData('media_gallery_images') && is_array($product->getMediaGallery('images'))) {
        $images = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        foreach ($product->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
            if ($image['disabled']) {
                continue;
            }
            if($min!==$max AND ( $image['position']<$min OR $image['position']>$max )){
                continue;
            }
            $image['url'] = $product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
            $image['id'] = isset($image['value_id']) ? $image['value_id'] : null;
            $image['path'] = $product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaPath($image['file']);
            $images->addItem(new Varien_Object($image));
        }
        return $images;
    }
}
```

Note that I added a fallback for all previous call to this function, the min and max will both be at 0 disabling the extra thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new image attribute *slideshow_image* to the products attribute set. [This post](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2012/12/adding-a-fourth-image-position-to-the-admin-for-a-magento-product/) on pixafy explains how. This would enable you to retrieve all the images for the product collection slidehow by search for the images in the *slideshow_image* attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so, that helps me for another topic, but not for this one. The issue here is that with this solution, I can get only 1 image for my slideshow, I need more than 1... in other words, your solution adds a column of radio buttons while I need a column of tickboxes.